# where are the chat messages stored in socket.io

Tags: socket.io

Hi,

I was in the middle of developing a PHP chat that stores the messages and user sessions in text files when I learned about socket.io and I would like to switch to this method instead because seems to save CPU usage on my server (currently I have to do GET requests of the php files to load messages and users every 2 seconds).

My question is, are the messages stored somewhere with socket.io? How about the user sessions with their data such as username and profiles? I get all that from a database via PHP as of now and then store it a temporary text session file.

Thanks.

Comment: Socket.io requires a NodeJS server, not PHP. How are you planning on integrating Socket.io into your application, exactly?

Comment: (Also, PHP's lack of inter-request state is another reason to consider ditching PHP entirely; imo)

Comment: I know. I had my host install node.js so thats fine. I want users to log in with the data that I already have from the database. So lets say my first page is a php page. This will load the data from the database and store it in a text file. Thats why Im asking where is all that stored with socket.io if stored at all.

Comment: Have you read Socket.io's documentation at all? SocketIO is just a WebSocket library, it doesn't have its own storage or persistence layer: that's your responsibility.

Comment: BTW, you are aware that PHP and NodeJS don't share any state? (e.g. your PHP `$_SESSION` is unavailable to NodeJS, and vice-versa)?

Comment: I read all through it but honestly I dont quite get it and thats why Im here. I am totally new to websocket to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

> are the messages stored somewhere with socket.io?

No: Socket.io is just a WebSocket library. It's your responsibility as an application developer to *use* socket.io to receive incoming messages which runs your own code that loads or generates responses and vice-versa. So asking that question is like asking "are the messages stored somewhere with PHP?".

> How about the user sessions with their data such as username and profiles?

Again, socket.io is just a library for using WebSockets. It does not have any user or profile management features built-in. It's your responsibility to build or integrate that into your NodeJS code which then uses socket.io

> I get all that from a database via PHP as of now and then store it a temporary text session file.

You'll need to keep on doing just that (though you should also store the chat messages in your database too, as using text files won't scale to more than a handful of concurrent users).

Note that unlike PHP websites, NodeJS applications do have semi-persistent, in-memory state (so you can load data from your database and use it in-between requests instead of reloading everything for each new page request or websocket message) but remember that that state will be lost when the NodeJS server shuts-down, crashes, or is killed by your web-host's management infrastructure. Also when you do eventually scale to multiple server instances each one is isolated from each other, so their in-memory state won't be shared. If you absolutely need to share some kind of low-latency (but not in-memory state) then consider using something like `memcached` or Redis).

Comment: I will try to be more specific. Look at the demo here: https://socket.io/demos/chat/ it prompts you to input a username. Where is that data stored in this case?